# Continuous parsing and processing of text

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

I have a class that's a listener to a log server. The listener gets notified whenever a log/text is spewed out. I store this text in an arraylist.

I need to process this text (remove duplicate words, store it in a trie, compare it against some patterns etc).

My question is should i be doing this as an when the listener is notified? Or should i be creating a separate thread that handles the processing.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question once more to fix typos and clarify it further?

Comment: how often is the listener notified? How long do it take to process the text? Of time spent processing the text how long is it spent actually reading the file? There are a lot of factors that determine whether or not threading is necessary for your needs but I would guess that yes threading is the way you want to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to solve the [Producer Consumer Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem), in which case - **Yes**, you should be looking at threads.

If, however, you only need to do very basic operations that take less than milliseconds per entry - don't overly complicate things. If you use a TreeSet in conjunction with an ArrayList  - it will automatically take care of keeping duplicates out. Simple atomic operations such as validating the log entry aren't such a big deal that they need a seperate thread, unless new text is coming in at such a rapid rate that you need to need a thread to busy itself full time with processing new notifications.

Answer (score 1):

The process that are not related to UI i always run that type of process in  separate thread so it will not hang your app screen. So as my point of view you need to go with separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Such a situation can be solved using [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)s. The simplest solution would be to have an unbounded blocking queue (a [LinkedTransferQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html) is tailored for such a case) and a limited size pool of worker threads.
You would [add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#add%28E%29)/[offer()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer%28E%29) the log entry from the listener's thread and [take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) for processing with worker threads. [take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) will block a thread if no log entries are available for processing.

P. S. A [LinkedTransferQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html) is designed for concurrent usage, no external synchronization is necessary: it's based on *weak* iterators, just like the Concurrent DS family.